# Batch file text processing - find consecutive numbers

Tags: batch-file, range, sequence

I have a text file that contains telephone long distance exchange info for a PBX. 
input file contains:

```
sourceNPA,srcNNX,DestinationNPA,destNNX
954,327,954,201
954,327,954,202
954,327,954,203
954,327,954,210 
954,327,954,212
954,327,954,213 
954,327,954,214 
etc...
```

I can't use any but VBS or Windows batch for company policy reasons (not just because I'm not a coder). I'm expected to do these by hand but there's 43000 or more to be converted to ranges.

I need to read each line of the given text file, see if the dNPA and dNXX (last two arg in each line) are consecutive and if so determine the range so the input list would read as follows in the output:

```
954,327,954,201,203
954,327,954,210,210
954,327,954,212,214
etc...
```

I've tried studying the use of arrays and tried reading a single line to a temp file but there has to be a trick for this.

I've been tinkering but have little to show for it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set lineNumber=1
if exist outputFile.txt del outputFile.txt

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=,;" %%a in (inputFile.txt) do call :process %%a %%b %%c %%d
:EOF

:process
set line!linenumber!SrcNPA=%1
set line!linenumber!SrcNNX=%2
set line!linenumber!destNPA=%3
set line!linenumber!destNNX=%4
REM then intended to compare the values but I'm stuck
REM I want to compare the last arugment of each line to the same
REM same argument in the next line read, and if its sequential 
REM then set the start the range and when the comaparison is no longer
REM consecutive set the top of the range andn then write that range to output
set /a lineNumber+=1
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to process a file containing a list of numbers that are formatted like the first sequence listed where some are consecutive and output a list of numbers that are formatted like the second list of numbers where in the consecutive numbers in the input are converted to ranges in the output.

Comment: The code sample is just weak but that's why I'm asking for advice. I've tried several things but I think I'm chasing my tail here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do math on the 4th number to look for consecutive values. Presumably some of the numbers can start with zero. This causes a parsing problem for batch because SET /A assumes numbers starting with 0 are in octal notation. So extra work is required to protect against that.

Assuming the input file is presorted, the following should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "current="
set "next="
(
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in (testFile.txt) do (
    set /a "num=10000%%D%%10000"
    if "!current!,!next!"=="%%A,%%B,%%C,!num!" (
      set "end=%%D"
      set /a "next+=1"
    ) else (
      if defined current echo !current!,!start!,!end!
      set "current=%%A,%%B,%%C"
      set "start=%%D"
      set "end=%%D"
      set /a "next=num+1"
    )
  )
  if defined current echo !current!,!start!,!end!
)>global_new.txt
```

If the input file is not presorted, then you can use SORT in your FOR /F as long as the width of each column is constant.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('sort testFile.txt') do (
```

If the widths of the columns is not constant and the file is not presorted, then the script becomes much more complicated. I suggest switching to VBS at that point. VBS is going to have much better performance anyway.

Comment: Perfect! It worked just as you posted. There are techniques in there that I'd not seen before. Good stuff to study. Brilliant! All the input will be formatted just as described so this will work for the entire job... This will save me hours if not longer. Thanks for the fast advice.